# How to upgrade Camunda from 7.12 to 7.15 in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda

I've been scratching my head over the update docs to figure out how to upgrade the Camunda version. It's just so amazingly complex for some reason due to seemingly large number of compatibility issues with every upgrade of Camunda.
Can someone please guide on how can I migrate Camunda from 7.12 to 7.15?

PS: I'm not using the REST api.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation lists all significant changes made to the application configuration or behavior, but this does not mean that everything applies to you or that the upgrade is going to be complex.

> If you need to apply multiple minor versions you MUST execute the
> database alteration scripts in minor version order as they are NOT
> cumulative. Application library updates are cumulative and don’t
> necessarily require sequential minor version updates. You can just
> apply your target minor application libraries. You should, however,
> check the migration guide of EVERY intermediate minor version to
> understand all noteworthy changes in behavior.

(src: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/update/minor/ )

So you need to see in sequence

1. https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/update/minor/712-to-713/
2. https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/update/minor/713-to-714/
3. https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/update/minor/714-to-715/

to determine the necessary database upgrades and understand what has changed.

A summary of the database patch scripts and tickets describing the modifications is available here: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/update/patch-level/#database-patches

The scripts can be downloaded from https://app.camunda.com/nexus/service/rest/repository/browse/public/org/camunda/bpm/distro/camunda-sql-scripts/

On CAMUNDA API level you won't have to deal with breaking changes. It stays backwards compatible. The CAMUNDA Spring Boot starters have evolved and in the newer versions you may need less config.

The CAMUNDA starters upgrade the Spring Boot version they depend on.
Depending on the extent to which you are using Spring Boot this may have the biggest impact on you. Spring Boot may have breaking changes and many libraries will have regular upgrades included. If you are just using the occasional @Component and @Autowired then the Spring boot upgrade also won't be difficult.

Good luck.